# Узнать место на Sd-card или Внутренеей памяти Android

Tags: java, android

Узнать место на Sd-card или Внутренеей памяти Android 
какие методы?

Answer (score 0):

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();` - это для внешнего хранилища требуется разрешение на запись чтение с карточки, и начиная с `Api21` еще и получить это разрешение по ходу работы.(Но на Api14(4.4.4) даёт внутренюю память устройства (которую видит пользователь)
`Environment.getInternalStorageDirectory().toString();` - сам не пользовался, но существует

`Context.getFilesDir();` - получает внутренний каталог расположений в /data/data/ и доступный только приложению
`Context.getCacheDir();` - получает внутренний каталог кеша, он может быть снесён системой.
Все методы представляют путь как `String`
 `Context` бери как `this`(при вызове из `Activity`), либо передай её в метод внешнего класса (как `Context`, в вызывающий пиши `this`) и там применяй.